# Unwanted blank space on top table cells when embedding table view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I'm working on this ios app and using segmented control I'm trying to have 2 overlapping container views and depending on which segment option is selected, show/hide the appropriate view. However, after the container in my view and setting it to take up the whole screen, i embedded another table view controller inside (ctrl + select the table view controller and selecting Embed). My issue is that for some reason it appears that on top of my table there is a blank space and I'm not sure how to get it out of the way. The table view controller is embedded in a navigation controller but I tried removing the navigation and it still doesn't work.
The unwanted blank section is marked in red below.
I'm using xcode 7 with swift 2.
Any help would really be appreciated,
Thanks!

[image: Unwanted space marked in red]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to set the constraint on the top your container to match the top of the view controller's view, rather than the top layout guide.

This way, the tableview will extend below the navigation bar, but the top layout guide will add the margin which you see so that it remains fully visible.